# Can a loop be terminated early externally?

Tags: python, raspberry-pi

I am writing some Python code that plays a buzzer tone pattern until a button is pressed, which switches the pattern to the next one in the `while True:` loop. I have not included the module imports or the button and buzzer declarations for brevity. Also, at the end of each loop, it can be assumed that the buzzer will be in the off position.

```
i = 1 # the current pattern
patterns = 2 # total number of patterns, or last pattern

def buttonClicked(): # changes i when button is pressed
    if i > patterns:
        i = 1
    else:
        i = i + 1

while True:

    while i == 1:
        # buzzer on
        # sleep
        # buzzer off

    while i == 2:
        #buzzer on
        #sleep
        #buzzer off
        #sleep
        #buzzer on
        #sleep
        #buzzer off
```

I know this solution is not the best, but it has worked for the most part except for one thing. With the current set up, `i` is only checked if it was incremented at the beginning of each inner loop, so the pattern would have to finish to switch to the next one (if the button was pressed). This is problematic since a single iteration of some patterns (not shown for brevity) can last up to 10 seconds.

To the good stuff:
**How can I get the button to immediately trigger a switch in patterns?**

I have looked into using multiple threads, as the standard method for the button executes immediately once the button is pressed, but I do not know how to stop the `while` loop after the button is pressed. This behavior is similar to that of an event listener in JavaScript.

Here is some documentation I looked at for the button read: https://gpiozero.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api_input.html#gpiozero.Button.when_pressed

Answer (score 0):

How about this?

```
step = 0 # where we are in the cycle
patterns = [ # time to sleep between on/off
    [0.5, 1.0],
    [2.0, 3.0, 4.5, 1.0],
]

while True:
    if step % 2 == 0: # even cycle
        # buzzer on
    else: # odd cycle
        # buzzer off
    pat = patterns[i]
    sleep(pat[step % len(pat)])
    step += 1
```

This way, the maximum delay is the largest sleep time, not an entire pattern.  And the code is more compact, and data-driven (just one line per pattern).

Comment: This is a great solution, but the buzzer itself is connected to multiple outputs so this won't quite work as-is. Each output is connected to a transistor that gives the buzzer a certain voltage. By using this setup with varying resistances, the buzzer make noise at varying volumes. Within the code, a "pattern" is essentially a sequence of changing sounds through different output pins. Sorry I didn't mention this in the original post, but thanks anyway.

Comment: @ERN: I guess you can put tuples in the `patterns` lists, saying how long to wait and also which outputs to use at each step.